# PHP to Java (using PtoJ)

Tags: java, php

I would like to transition our codebase from poorly written PHP code to poorly written Java, since I believe Java code is easier to tidy up. What are the pros and cons, and for those who have done it yourselves, would you recommend [PtoJ](http://www.numiton.com/products/ntile-ptoj/ptoj-overview.html) for a project of about 300k ugly lines of code? Tips and tricks are most welcome; thanks!

Comment: Honestly, an converting an ugly codebase is bound to make it uglier, whether Java is cleaner or not (which, by the way, is not **;)**).

Comment: You're right, I'm just hoping that we in time will get the Java code in better shape than the PHP ditto is right now. Do you think it's a lost cause?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Poorly written PHP is likely to be very hard to convert because a lot of the bad stuff in PHP just doesn't exist in Java (the same is true vice versa though, so don't take that as me saying Java is better - I'm going to keep well clear of that flame-war).

If you're talking about a legacy PHP app, then its highly likely that your code contains a lot of procedural code and inline HTML, neither of which are going to convert well to Java.

If you're really unlucky, you'll have things like `eval()` statements, dynamic variable names (using `$$` syntax), looped `include()` statements, reliance on the 'register_globals' flag, and worse. That kind of stuff will completely thwart any conversion attempt.

Your other major problem is that debugging the result after the conversion is going to be hell, even if you have beautiful code to start with. If you want to avoid regressions, you will basically need to go through the entire code base on both sides with a fine comb.

The only time you're going to get a satisfactory result from an automated conversion of this type is if you start with a reasonably tide code base, written at least mainly in up-to-date OOP code.

In my opinion, you'd be better off doing the refacting excersise before the conversion. But of course, given your question, that would rather defeat the point. Therefore my recommendation is to stick it in PHP. PHP code can be very good, and even bad PHP can be polished up with a bit of refactoring.

[EDIT]

In answer to @Jonas's question in the comments, 'what is the best way to refactor horrible PHP code?'

It really depends on the nature of the code. A large monolithic block of code (which describes a lot of the bad PHP I've seen) can be very hard  (if not imposible) to implementunit tests for. You may find that functional tests are the only kind of tests you can write on the old code base. These would use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or similar tools to run the code through the browser as if it were a user. If you can get a set of reliable functional tests written, it is good for helping you remain confident that you aren't introducing regressions.

The good news is that it can be very easy - and satisfying - to rip apart bad code and rebuild it.

The way I've approached it in the past is to take a two-stage approach.

Stage one rewrites the monolithic code into decent quality procedural code. This is relatively easy, and the new code can be dropped into place as you go. This is where the bulk of the work happens, but you'll still end up with procedural code. Just better procedural code.

Stage two: once you've got a critical mass of reasonable quality procedural code, you can then refactor it again into an OOP model. This has to wait until later, because it is typically quite hard to convert old bad quality PHP straight into a set of objects. It also has to be done in fairly large chunks because you'll be moving large amounts of code into objects all at once. But if you did a good job in stage one, then stage two should be fairly straightforward.

When you've got it into objects, then you can start seriously thinking about unit tests.

Comment: What is the best way to refactor horrible PHP code? Make it testable and implement a lot of unit tests then start tearing it apart?

Comment: @Jonas -- my reply to your comment is too big to put in the comments here, so I've edited my answer; see above.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that automatic conversion from PHP to Java have the following:

**pros**:

- quick and dirty, possibly making happy some project manager concerned with short-time delivery (assuming that you're lucky and the automatically generated code works without too much debugging, which I doubt)

**cons**:

- ugly code: I doubt that automatic conversion from ugly PHP will generate anything but ugly Java
- unmaintainable code: the automatically generate code is likely to be unmaintainable, or, at least, very difficult to maintain
- bad approach: I assume you have a PHP Web application; in this case, I think that the automatic translation is unlikely to use Java best practices for Web application, or available frameworks

**In summary**

I would avoid automatic translation from PHP to Java, and I woudl at least consider rewriting the application from the ground up using Java. Especially if you have a Web application, choose a good Java framework for webapps, do a careful design, and proceed with an incremental implementation (one feature of your original PHP webapp at a time). With this approach, you'll end up with cleaner code that is easier to maintain and evolve ... and you may find out that the required time is not that bigger that what you'd need to clean/debug automatically generated code :)

Answer (score 3):

[P2J](http://www.numiton.com/products/ntile-ptoj/ptoj-overview.html) appears to be offline now, but I've written a proof-of-concept that converts a subset of PHP into Java. It uses the [transpiler](https://github.com/jarble/transpiler) library for SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(transpiler)).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).
:- initialization(main).

main :- 
    Input = "function add($a,$b){ print $a.$b; return $a.$b;} function squared($a){ return $a*$a; } function add_exclamation_point($parameter){return $parameter.\"!\";}",
    translate(Input,'php','java',X),
    atom_chars(Y,X),
    writeln(Y).
```

This is the program's output:

```
public static String add(String a,String b){
        System.out.println(a+b);
        return a+b;
}
public static int squared(int a){
        return a*a;
}
public static String add_exclamation_point(String parameter){
        return parameter+"!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.numiton.com/products/ntile-ptoj/translation-samples/web-and-db-access/mysql.html

Would you rather not use Hibernate ?

Comment: I probably would (haven't used it). In fact, I'd rather use almost anything else than what we've got now. :)

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to other answers here, I would agree with your strategy to convert "PHP code to poorly written Java, since I believe Java code is easier to tidy up", but you need to make sure the tool that you are using doesn't introduce more bugs than you can handle.

An optimum stategy would be:
1) Do automated conversion
2) Get an MVP running with some basic tests
3) Start using the amazing Eclipse/IntelliJ refractoring tool to make the code more readable.

A modern Java IDE can refactor code with zero bugs when done properly. It can also tell you which functions are never called and a lot of other inspections.

I don't know how "PtoJ" was, since their website has vanished, but you ideally want something that doesn't just translate the syntax, but the logic. I used php2java.com recently and it worked very well. I've also used various "syntax" converters (not just for PHP to Java, but also ObjC -> Swift, Java -> Swift), and even they work just fine if you put in the time to make things work after.

Also, found this interesting blog entry about what might have happened to numiton PtoJ (http://www.runtimeconverter.com/single-post/2017/11/14/What-happened-to-numition).